Как включить offline-режим браузера?
Как сделать так, чтобы браузер отображал только локальные html-файлы, не связываясь с сетевыми ресурсами? Так сказать имитировать работу при отсутствии интернет-соединения.
Видел пару расширений для Chrome, но они мешают нормальной работе с локальными html-файлами.

Хм, не пробовали отключать интернет-соединение?

Это рабочий вариант, но очень не удобный. Хотелось бы иметь offline-режим только в одном месте, без ограничений в другом браузере. Можно ещё виртуальную машину использовать, но это тоже долго, неудобно и громоздко.

В хроме в инструментах разработчика (F12) есть возможность настроить искусственную задержку сети. Там же  можно выбрать параметр offline. Но работает это только пока открыта вкладка с инструментами разработки.

@Стас, спасибо, пока что это самое близкое к желаемому решение. Но всё же не идеальное. Этот параметр прерывает только исходящие сообщения, но не мешает "слушать" уже существующие соединения, установленные до его включения.
Существует ли более надёжный способ изолировать браузер от сети?

@Kram, скормить ему битый прокси?

FireFox в автономной работе так и работает - локальные открывает, в инет не лезет.
